# Difference between model(x) and model.predict(x) on Retracing Computation Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used a `for` loop to load several models in `.H5` format and make predictions with each one of them on the same test tensor `X_test`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

predictions = []
for path in model_paths:
    model = load_model(path, compile=False)
    pred = model(X_test)
    predictions.append(pred)
```

An alternative to this:

```
pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Is this:

```
pred = model(X_test)
```

Notably, the first alternative has raised a warning about retracing the computation graph many times, while the second option hasn't raised this error.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 13 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x7f03b01ad430> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

I was wondering what is the difference between the `model(X_test)` and `model.predict(X_test)` regarding retracing.